# DynamoDB Java AWS SDK - UpdateItem simplification possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to using AWS and am writing something that will add an attribute to the provided item given some keyAttributes. I got it working, but the code I ended up writing just looks unintuitive and silly to me. (I just based it off of documentation I've been finding online.)

I was able to do a successful basic update of an item in a dynamoDB table with this code:

```
final AttributeValue fulfilled = new AttributeValue().withBOOL(true);

final UpdateItemRequest updateItemRequest = new UpdateItemRequest()
     .withTableName(tableName)
     .withKey(keyAttributes)
     .withUpdateExpression("SET fulfilled = :fulfilled")
     .withExpressionAttributeValues(ImmutableMap.of(":fulfilled", fulfilled));

final UpdateItemResult result = dynamoClient.updateItem(updateItemRequest);
```

Is there anything I can do to cut it down to just the barebones thing I'm trying to do here: just adding a new attribute "fulfilled" to an item, set to true?

Answer (score 1):

An `UpdateItemRequest` must always contain the table name and the key attributes. (Otherwise how would DynamoDB know which item to update?)

You can simplify it, though, by getting rid of the `ExpressionAttributeValues`, like this:

```
final UpdateItemRequest updateItemRequest = new UpdateItemRequest()
        .withTableName(tableName)
        .withKey(keyAttributes)
        .withUpdateExpression("SET fulfilled = TRUE");

final UpdateItemResult result = dynamoClient.updateItem(updateItemRequest);
```

Comment: When I do this, I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: Invalid UpdateExpression: Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: TRUE
```

Comment: That’s odd. In this case `TRUE` should be an attribute value, not an attribute name as DynamoDB seems to think. I’m going to look into this because that doesn’t seem consistent with how DynamoDB generally works.